# Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I followed this guide( https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/)  to create a modular application with IntelliJ IDE but it doesn't run, just got this error:

`Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 18: D:/Java/javafx/lib:mods/production`.

I don't know why this error occurs and how to fix it. I am so grateful if anyone has a solution or advice. Thanks for reading.

Comment: [Edit] your question and post the entire stack trace of the error you are getting.

Comment: Error message says your path has colon **/lib:mods**,  check where is this path used and avoid colon in the path

Comment: I use --module-path ${PATH_TO_FX}:mods/production like guide

Comment: Do you use Maven or Gradle? Do you use WSL? Please include full stack trace of the error.